# How set PRODUCT_NAME in Xcode "Build Phases"

Tags: xcode, macos, configuration

I have JSON file with build configuration properties. This file contains information about application name. I want set this file in Xcode "Build Phases" using shell.
or if it is possible set this name in new target dependence script file (can be shell script).

How can I change PRODUCT_NAME xcode build configuration variable in "Build Phases" ?

I try create xcconfig file. Set file name in this file and use it. But "Build Phases" script run after this file loaded.